# Bash script: Copies image files from source dir to destination dir and adds an extra suffix on files with same file name

Tags: image, bash, text, rename

I have this script that copies image files from source directory to destination directory. There are some image files in the source directory that have the same name but different file size. This script also compares the two files with the same name using a **stat** command. Now, I want to add a string suffix e.g. IMG0897.DUP.JPG before the file extension to the files with the same file name that are going to be copied over to the destination folder. At the moment, my script adds the file size of the file to the file name.

I need help on how to add a string of text of my own rather than the size of the file.
Here's my script:

```
#!/bin/sh
SEARCH="IMG_*.JPG"
SOURCE= $1
DEST=$2
test $# -ne 2 && echo Usage : phar image_path archive_path
if [ ! -e $1 ]
then  echo Source folder does not exist
fi
if [ ! -e $2 ]
then mkdir $2/
fi
# Execute the script.

    if [ "${SEARCH%% *}" = "$SEARCH" ]; then
        command="find \"$1\" -name \"$SEARCH\""
    else
        command="find \"$1\" -name \"${SEARCH%% *}\""$(for i in ${SEARCH#* }; do echo -n " -o -name \"$i\""; done)
    fi

    # Run the main loop.
    eval "$command" | while read file; do
        bn=$(basename "$file")
        bc=$(stat -c%s "$file")
        if [ -f "${2}/$bn" ] && [ "$bc" -ne $(stat -c%s "${2}/$bn") ]; then
        bn="$bn.$bc"
     fi
        if [ -f "${2}/$bn" ]; then
            echo "File ${2}/$bn already exists."
        else
            echo "Copying $file to $2/$bn"
            cp -a "$file" "$2/$bn"
        fi
    done
    exit 0
else
    echo "Error : Can't find $1 or $2"
    exit 1
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your scripte slightly.

```
#!/bin/sh
SEARCH="IMG_*.JPG"
SOURCE=$1
DEST=$2
SUFFIX=DUP
test $# -ne 2 && echo Usage : phar image_path archive_path
if [ ! -e $1 ]
then  echo Source folder does not exist
fi
if [ ! -e $2 ]
then mkdir $2/
fi
# Execute the script.

    if [ "${SEARCH%% *}" = "$SEARCH" ]; then
        command="find \"$1\" -name \"$SEARCH\""
    else
        command="find \"$1\" -name \"${SEARCH%% *}\""$(for i in ${SEARCH#* }; do echo -n " -o -name \"$i\""; done)
    fi

    # Run the main loop.
    eval "$command" | while read file; do
        bn=$(basename "$file")
        bc=$(stat -c%s "$file")
        if [ -f "${2}/$bn" ] && [ "$bc" -ne $(stat -c%s "${2}/$bn") ]; then
            bc=$(echo ${bn}|cut -d. -f2)
            bn=$(echo ${bn}|cut -d. -f1)
            bn=$bn.$SUFFIX.$bc**
        fi
        if [ -f "${2}/$bn" ]; then
            echo "File ${2}/$bn already exists."
        else
            echo "Copying $file to $2/$bn"
            cp -a "$file" "$2/$bn"
        fi
    done
    exit 0
else
    echo "Error : Can't find $1 or $2"
    exit 1
fi
```

My execution result is:

> root@precise32:/vagrant# sh JPG_moves.sh /root/dir1/ /root/destination/
> Copying /root/dir1/IMG_0897.JPG to /root/destination//IMG_0897.JPG
>
> root@precise32:/vagrant# sh JPG_moves.sh /root/dir2/ /root/destination/
> Copying /root/dir2/IMG_0897.JPG to /root/destination//IMG_0897.DUP.JPG

Comment: Fantastic! Just what I wanted. Thank you so much!